# How to find the PID of a C code during compilation time?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

How to find the PID of a C code which is being executed So that I can find its stack and heap memory usage? And also can anyone ellaborate me about the sections in the map file?

Comment: what do u mean by 'pid of a c code' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437602/shell-script-to-get-the-process-id-on-linux 
Maybe this link can help you

Comment: @tristan: pid of a C code means the PID assigned by the linux kernel for the execution of the code

Comment: It's confusing. kernel doesn't assign id for a piece of code. It's process ID. The same code might be used by multiple processes.

Comment: @tristan: Ok fine ! can you help me find the stack and heap memory used by the C code I'm building in linux platform?

Comment: @Siva: you should understand that a process is not the same as an executable. Follow the links I gave you in my answer!

Comment: @OMerObaid: Nope.. It wasn't useful :(

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Ok bro ! My aim is to get the details of the usage of stack and heap memory of a C code I'm compiling in Linux.. Could u plz help me?

Comment: Again, stack and heap exist only for running processes, not for passive C code. I added even more HTML links in my answer for you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: For a running process only I'm asking bro ! When the C code is getting compiled it'll be in running state right?

Comment: No, only when you run the compiled ELF executable. What happens at compile time is irrelevant!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Ok.. So there is any way to find the space that our code occupies in stack and heap when running in linux?

Comment: It is one of the worst asked questions I answered to .... If I could I would downvote more than once.

Comment: @Siva i think Basile wanna say you can not do this. "**stack and heap exist only for running processes, not for passive C code.**"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Then y the hell did u answer? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not the getpid() method defined in unistd.h?

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    int pid = getpid();
    int parentsPID = getppid();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't think so he wants this

Answer (score 2):

PID exists only for running process. That means your c code should be running. In your c code can use `getpid();` to get current process ID. This should be call from your c code which you need pid. You can print the pid and can look in to `/proc` entries of that pid. Or you can read `/proc` entries from your program after gettign PID. (OR) When yoou run your c code, Use ps -ef command to print details of all running processes. In that you'll find a field called pid. you can identify your executable pid from its name.

Comment: If my code is running, Where to type the code ps -ef command?

Comment: Open a new shell and type there.

Comment: I'm using Linux vmbox terminal window.. And moreover my code is running in a target board.. So plz explain how'll I find the stack and heap memory usage of the C code which I'm executing?

Comment: You could and should install a shell and some command line utilities (perhaps with telnet and sshd) on the target board.

Answer (score 1):

A C code is only a bunch of textual source files.

It can be built, i.e. [compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) then [linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (and perhaps [installed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_%28computer_programs%29)), as an [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) program (often in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) on Linux).

That executable may be executed by the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall from inside some [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29)-ed [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_process). Each process has its *pid* (a unique positive number of type `pid_t`). On Linux, you may have several different processes running the same executable (in particular, you usually have several running `/bin/bash` shells, e.g. one for each terminal).

From inside a process, use the [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) syscall to get its *pid*. Read also more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). Use also the [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) and [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) commands (in particular, try `ps auxw`)

The `/proc/$PID/maps` (which, from inside the application, you can access as `/proc/self/maps`) gives the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) of the process. That space has been set-up by `execve` and changed by various [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (mostly [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and related syscalls, which also get called by the dynamic loader [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), by [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), etc... etc...). Be aware of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)...

Your question shows that you probably should take several hours to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to understand more the relevant concepts and the terminology.

Stack and heap don't exist inside the C code, they makes sense only inside a process! If you want to measure them from inside your application, use various files from `/proc/self/` notably read sequentially `/proc/self/maps`, `/proc/self/status`, `/proc/self/stat`, `/proc/self/statm` etc... From outside the application, use `/proc/$PID/` (e.g. `/proc/1234/` for the process of pid 1234), and also use the [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) command (which queries `/proc/`). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514624/841108).

BTW, one cannot in general get the lowest upper and highest lower bound[s] of stack and heap usage by static examination and [analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) of the C source code (this is an [intractable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intractability_%28complexity%29) or an [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) problem). See [Rice's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)...

---

PS. The `ps`, `top`, `pmap` (etc ....) commands should be run (and the `/proc` filesystem should be accessed) on the Linux system running your executable built from your C code. If you are using Linux/x86-64 to [cross-compile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) for an Android/ARM or a embedded Linux/ARM board, you should have `/proc/` [mounted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29) on that embedded board, and you should run (remotely, using `ssh` or `telnet` etc....) the commands on that board.

Comment: Its not clear for me.. Could you plz explain me where will I find the stack and heap memory usage of the C code that I'm executing?

Comment: Please take several hours to follow all the references. As you ask it, **your question does not make any sense**: process, stack, heap are dynamic (at runtime), C code is static (at compile time).

Comment: I'm asking about the procedure to find the memory used by the code(i.e stack and heap) during the run time only.

Comment: I've answered to that above. Please follow the links